# Save File as CSV UTF8 gives error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to save the contents of a worksheet which has Chinese characters in many cells. I got the below code using a recorded macro.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("input").SaveAs fileName:="D:\File1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8
```

But when I run it I get runtime error 1004: *Method SaveAs of object _workbook failed*.

If I change `FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8` to `FileFormat:=xlCSV`, then it works correctly but the Chinese characters are saved in the CSV file as question marks because of the missing UTF-8.

How do I save a CSV file and preserve UTF-8 encoding in VBA?

Comment: Have a look e.g. [here](http://access-excel.tips/export-chinese-excel-to-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft appears to have added a CSV UTF8 save option to Excel in the last month or two.  [User voice](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10006149-support-saving-csv-in-utf-8-encoding) says this was released over 9 months ago, but I know I didn't have this option in May.

I used FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8 in code today, and it correctly saved the CSV file with Chinese characters.  I'm using Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.7726.1049) 32-bit.